# Find minimum value at each index after queries which tell you minimum value over a range

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Assume that initially in array `a` each element has infinity as value.

Now `M` queries are input of the type `l` `r` `x`.

Here `l` to `r` is range where value need to be updated if `a[i]>x` where `l<=i<=r` and `l<=r<=n`.

After `M` queries you need to output the minimum value at each index.

One way to this is to use Brute Force

```
memset(a,inf,sizeof(a));
while(j<m)
{
     scanf("%d %d %d",&l,&r,&c);
    for(i=l-1;i<r;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>c)
            a[i]=c;
    }

    j++;
}

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%d",a[i]);
```

Now this takes O(mn) time where n=size of each query which can be n in worst case.

What are more efficient ways to solve this in lesser time complexity?

Comment: "After M queries you need to output the minimum value at each index." Can you detail this please? Your pseudocode is not outputting anything.

Comment: It simply means that after M queries each index should have minimum possible value. I have made the edits.

Comment: In the second last sentence you say that `n` can be `n` in worst case!?

Comment: @Ulrich I mean to say that I worst case the size of range is equivalent to size of array.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of answering as a comment.

Comment: Well you can check my questions ! I have clearly done this problem

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** my answer assumes that the problem is online, so you must execute updates and queries as they arrive. An advantage of this is that my solution is more robust, allowing you to add more types of updates and queries in the same complexity. The disadvantage is that it might not be the absolute best choice for your problem if you're dealing with an offline problem.

---

You can use a [segment tree](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-sum-of-given-range/). Have each node in the segment tree store the minimum value set for its associated interval (initially infinity, something very large) and use a lazy update and query scheme.

**Update(left, right, c)**

```
Update(node, left, right, c):
  if node.interval does not intersect [left, right]:
    return
  if node.interval included in [left, right]:
    node.minimum = min(c, node.minimum)
    return

  Update(node.left, left, right, c)
  Update(node.right, left, right, c)
```

**Query(index)**

```
Query(node, minimum = infinity, index):
  if node.interval == [index, index]:
    return minimum

  if index included in node.left.interval:
    return Query(node.left, min(minimum, node.minimum), index)

  return Query(node.right, min(minimum, node.minimum), index)
```

Total complexity: `O(log n)` for each update and query operation. You need to call `Query` for every element in the end.

Comment: Is it necessary to use lazy update to improve upon complexity?

Comment: @user3933528 yes. If you eliminate the `return` in the second `if` condition of the `Update` function, the update complexity will be `O(n)`. Of course, you can then build the final answer in `O(n)` rather than `O(n log n)`, but the same is true for your algorithm.

Comment: I think it would be equivalent to using naive approach if lazy propagation is not used.

Comment: Have you included lazy propagation in query because I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: @user3933528 lazy propagation is used in my pseudocode. It's just a fancy term, implementation-wise it's basically just the return I told you about. If you implement the pseudocode as I posted it, you'll get the efficient `O(log n) / query` algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

There is an approach that has a different asymptotic complexity. It involves keeping a sorted list of begin and end of queries. In order to avoid actual sorting, I'm using a sparse array the size of `a`.

Now, the general idea is that you store the queries and while iterating you keep a heap containing the queries is who's range you are:

```
# size of array (n)
count = ...
# for each array element you have a list of ranges that
# start or end at this array element
list<queries> l[count]
list<queries> r[count]
heap<queries> h
for i in range(count):
    if l[i]:
        h.push(l[i])
    if h is empty:
        output(inf)
    else:
        output(h.lowest().value)
    if r[i]:
        h.pop(r[i])
```

The actual performance of this (and other algorithms) greatly depends on the size of the array and density of the queries, none of which is covered in the asymptotic complexity of this algorithm though. Finding an optimal algorithm can't be done while ignoring the actual input data. It could also be worthwhile to change algorithms depending on the data.

Comment: Note that this assumes that the problem is offline. If you must execute each update as it arrives, you can't do this. Of course, for the problem at hand it's probably offline, since there's only one query at the end, so +1.

Comment: That's true, @IVlad. The description and example code suggest to me that handling the queries and giving the results are two separate stages.